# How to pass a variable from one function to another function in same controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, controller

I have tried to pass a variable form a function to another function in same controller in codeigniter. I have used following code

```
redirect('fornt/fullcommunity',$project_encode_id);
```

here fornt is the name of the controller,
full community is the function inside the controller
$project_encode_id is the variable to pass
but it is not working

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking here, but it sounds like you could simply do `$this->othermethod($project_encode_id);` So if this is wrong you are going to have to explain better what you are trying to do

Comment: What do you want to actually do here? Redirect to the controller or do you want to call the other method?

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would replace the redirect sentence with the following one:
$this->load->view(‘funLoadView’,$requiredVarForView);
Where the first parameter is the function in your controller, and the second one the data (possible array) that you need to include.
Both functions are on the same controller class so you don’t need to include any reference to the controller class name

Answer (score -1):

firsst you need to add your controller code.
Then, if bouth methods are in the same controller you only need to do this

```
class Your_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function method1(){
        $variable_form  = $this->input->post('form_variable', TRUE);
        //calling second method
        $response = $this->_method2($variable_form);
    }

    private function _method2 ( $str ){
        return 'do somthing -> ' . $str;
    }
}
```